# how to achieve image zooming with single image instead of large and small images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to provide zooming facility to uploaded image using follopoiurewqng technologies angularjs and couple of third party plugins like jqZoom and elevate zoom etc.

In my case, user can upload some images and then he/other user can see the upload image by zooming. But these third party plugins asking for small image and large image to provide the zooming facility. But user would upload single image, how to provide zooming with same image as large and small. I have tried in following way,

```
<script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("Linking")

            //Will watch for changes on the attribute
            attrs.$observe('zoomImage', function () {
                linkElevateZoom();
            })

            function linkElevateZoom() {
                //Check if its not empty
                if (!attrs.zoomImage) return;
                element.attr('data-zoom-image', attrs.zoomImage);
                $(element).elevateZoom();
            }

            linkElevateZoom();

        }
    };
});
```

**Html**

```
<img ng-elevate-zoom ng-src="{{mainImage}}" zoom-image="{{mainImage}}" />
```

Guide me how to achieve image zooming with single image instead of large and tiny images.

Comment: When a user uploads an image, does it mean the image is uploaded to server? If it is uploaded to server, can't the server provide url for thumbnails of the big image?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik yes it would be upload to Server.Generally will there any proportion between thumbnail and big image? because i need to generate  200X200 fixed thumnail to show as a preview, on hover user can zoom.

Comment: I guess the big image and thumbnail are supposed to have the same x/y ratio (it probably depends on the js zooming framework)? In that case the big image also needs to be cropped to a square size.